# Routing from private interface to public interface

Tags: routing, ubuntu-20.04

Our server has two interface, one for connecting through internet and the other for internal network.

```
172.20.54.10 -> Interface with static ip for connecting through internet
10.1.1.1     -> Internal network
```

The following configurations is seen

```
$ ip route
default via 172.20.54.1 dev enp12s0f1 proto static metric 20100
10.1.1.0/24 dev enp12s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.1 metric 101
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp12s0f1 scope link metric 1000
172.20.54.0/24 dev enp12s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.54.10 metric 100
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp12s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:81:e4:84:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.1/24 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp12s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a424:72eb:4702:8f86/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp12s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:81:e4:84:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.54.10/24 brd 172.20.54.255 scope global noprefixroute enp12s0f1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b0cf:3f53:bb4e:d836/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The internal network contains some VMs which have 10.1.1.X IP addresses and it seems that they are not connecting to the internet through the the public interface of the server. The server is Ubutnu 20.04.

Should I config something else for ip forwarding?

UPDATE:

The `ip_forward` is enabled in the kernel

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I also have to say that VMs, e.g 10.1.1.3, are able to ping the private interface, 10.1.1.1, but they are not able to ping 8.8.8.8.

[image]

Comment: You need (1) a route on the VMs that goes  through that server, and (2) kernel parameter `ip_forward` set to 1 on that server.

Comment: What is that route on VM? The VM is windows. I enabled `ip_forward` in the kernel with a reboot. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Did you configure SNAT?

Comment: For this configuration using the 10.* network. you need to use masquerading. see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-network-administrators/1565924002/ch11s03.html

Comment: On Windows, the command to display the routing table should be `route`. If the Linux server can access the internet, I don't think NAT is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you should use NAT.

Use the following rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp12s0f1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126596/118395 which says two iptables commands and I did the second too. Not sure that if two commands are needed or just one command is needed.

Comment: The second one is only necessary depending on your default forwarding policy (and other forwarding rules).